# Redirecting Calls from Amazon Connect to a WebSocket-Based Audio Application

Tags: websocket, amazon-connect

I'm working on integrating incoming telephone calls from Amazon Connect with a WebSocket-based audio application for internal use. The application handles audio streams and enables users to receive calls via WebSockets. The challenge is to redirect select calls received on Amazon Connect to this internal application. My initial approach was to use Twilio for routing these calls to an external number, but I'm seeking a more seamless solution that aligns closely with Amazon Connect's capabilities.

Is there a way to integrate Amazon Connect with a WebSocket-based system directly for handling telephone calls? I haven't found specific documentation covering this integration scenario on Amazon Connect. I would appreciate any advice, experiences, or resources that could guide me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable live audio streaming in Connect and send the audio for the call to a Kinesis Video stream.

The call stays in Connect while it is streaming so it isn't redirected. This is documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/adminguide/customer-voice-streams.html)

Comment: I understand that with this it is possible to hear what the user says and what the user hears. But it is not possible to send audio to the user.

Comment: That is correct. As far as I am aware there is no way to stream audio back to Connect. I'd love to do this to have a music stream for music on hold.

The only other thing you could do is write your own client using the connect-rtc-js library perhaps.... https://github.com/aws/connect-rtc-js